# How to set timeout for http.Get() requests in Golang?

Tags: http, get, timeout, go

I'm making a URL fetcher in Go and have a list of URLs to fetch. I send `http.Get()` requests to each URL and obtain their response.

```
resp,fetch_err := http.Get(url)
```

How can I set a custom timeout for each Get request? (The default time is very long and that makes my fetcher really slow.) I want my fetcher to have a timeout of around 40-45 seconds after which it should return "request timed out" and move on to the next URL.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just letting you guys know that I found this way more convenient (the dial timeout does not work well if there are network issues, at least for me): https://blog.golang.org/context

Comment: @Audrius Any idea why the dial timeout doesn't work when there are network issues? I think I'm seeing the same thing. I thought that's what DialTimeout was for?!?!

Comment: @Jordan Hard to tell as I did not dive that deep into the library code. I have posted my solution below. I'm using it in production for quite a while now and so far it "just works"(tm).

Answer (score 386, accepted):

Apparently in Go 1.3 [http.Client](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client) has Timeout field

```
client := http.Client{
    Timeout: 5 * time.Second,
}
client.Get(url)
```

That's done the trick for me.

Comment: Well, that's good enough for me.  Glad I scrolled down a bit :)

Comment: Is there a way to have a different timeout per request?

Comment: What happens when the timeout hits? Does `Get` return an error? I’m a little confused because the Godoc for `Client` says: _The timer remains running after Get, Head, Post, or Do return and will interrupt reading of the Response.Body._ So does that mean that _either_ `Get` _or_ reading `Response.Body` could be interrupted by an error?

Comment: Yes, it means that they can be interrupted. You'll see `net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while reading body)`. A way around this is to define your own transport or use something like https://github.com/mreiferson/go-httpclient

Comment: Question, what's the difference between `http.Client.Timeout` vs. `http.Transport.ResponseHeaderTimeout` ?

Comment: @Roylee One of the main differences according to the docs: `http.Client.Timeout` includes the time to read the response body, `http.Transport.ResponseHeaderTimeout` doesn't include it.

Comment: What if I then need to make request with that client with longer timeout?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75741987/how-to-override-the-default-timeout-of-an-http-client-in-go-for-specific-request

Answer (score 57):

You need to set up your own [Client](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client) with your own [Transport](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport) which uses a
custom Dial function which wraps around [DialTimeout](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#DialTimeout).

Something like (completely *untested*) [this](http://play.golang.org/p/nSEXVvAlwL):

```
var timeout = time.Duration(2 * time.Second)

func dialTimeout(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
    return net.DialTimeout(network, addr, timeout)
}

func main() {
    transport := http.Transport{
        Dial: dialTimeout,
    }

    client := http.Client{
        Transport: &transport,
    }

    resp, err := client.Get("http://some.url")
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly the thing I was looking for.

Comment: what's the advantage of using the net.DialTimeout over the Transport.ResponseHeaderTimeout described by the zzzz's answer?

Comment: @Daniel B: You are asking the wrong question. It is not about advantages but about what each code does. DialTimeouts jump in if the server cannot be dailed while other timeouts kick in if certain operations on the established connection take too long. If your target servers establish a connection quickly but then start to slow-ban you a dial timeout won't help.

Comment: @Volker, thanks for your answer. Actually I realized it as well: it looks like the Transport.ResponseHeaderTimeout sets the read timeout, that is the timeout after the connection has been established, while your is a dial timeout. The solution by dmichael deals with both dial timeout and read timeout.

Comment: not enough character to warrant an "edit": closing parenthesis need to move `time.Duration(2 * time.Second)` --> `time.Duration(2) * time.Second`

Comment: @Jonno: Why do you think so?

Comment: @Volker - my apologies - this is only true if the '2' in your example is a variable. I tried this: `a := 2` followed by `a * time.Second`. the go compiler complains: `invalid operation: a * time.Second (mismatched types int and time.Duration)`. in other words, you can't multiply int by duration - have to cast int to time.duration first. Said another way your example could be without the time.Duration casting - `var timeout = 2 * time.Second` i.e. the compiler does the necessary magic. BTW as reference my go version is go1.1.2 windows/amd64.

Comment: @Jonno: There are no casts in Go. These are type conversions.

Answer (score 54):

If you want to do it per request, err handling ignored for brevity:

```
ctx, cncl := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*3)
defer cncl()

req, _ := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, http.MethodGet, "https://google.com", nil)

resp, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
```

Comment: Extra info: per doc, the deadline imposed by Context encompasses also reading the Body, similarly to the `http.Client.Timeout`.

Comment: Should be an **accepted** answer for Go 1.7+. For Go 1.13+ can be slightly shortened using [NewRequestWithContext](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewRequestWithContext)

Answer (score 36):

To add to Volker's answer, if you would also like to set the read/write timeout in addition to the connect timeout you can do something like the following

```
package httpclient

import (
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func TimeoutDialer(cTimeout time.Duration, rwTimeout time.Duration) func(net, addr string) (c net.Conn, err error) {
    return func(netw, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
        conn, err := net.DialTimeout(netw, addr, cTimeout)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        conn.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(rwTimeout))
        return conn, nil
    }
}

func NewTimeoutClient(connectTimeout time.Duration, readWriteTimeout time.Duration) *http.Client {

    return &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            Dial: TimeoutDialer(connectTimeout, readWriteTimeout),
        },
    }
}
```

This code is tested and is working in production. The full gist with tests is available here
https://gist.github.com/dmichael/5710968

Be aware that you will need to create a new client for each request because of the `conn.SetDeadline` which references a point in the future from `time.Now()`

Comment: Shouldn't you check the return value of conn.SetDeadline?

Comment: This timeout doesn't work with keepalive connections, which is the default and what most people should be using I imagine. Here's what I came up with to deal with this: http://gist.github.com/seantalts/11266762

Comment: Thanks @xitrium and Eric for the additional input.

Comment: I feel like it is not as you said that we will need to create a new client for each request. Since Dial is a function which I think it gets call every time again you send each request in the same client.

Comment: You sure you need a new client each time? Each time it's dialing, instead of using net.Dial, it'll use the function that TimeoutDialer builds. That's a new connection, with the deadline evaluated each time, from a fresh time.Now() call.

Answer (score 27):

There are several client-side timeouts in the Go `http` module, and there are some samples of those timeouts on current answers.

Here is one image to illustrate the client-side timeout refer to [The complete guide to Go net/http timeouts](https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-complete-guide-to-golang-net-http-timeouts/)
[image]

There are two methods to set the timeout for HTTP request

- http.Client

```golang
client := http.Client{
    Timeout: 3 * time.Second,
}
resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

- Context

```golang
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 3*time.Second)
defer cancel()
req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, http.MethodGet, URL)
```

[The difference between them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64147364/3011380) is

> - Using context is request specific while using **the Client timeout might be applied to all request** pass to `Do` method client has.
> - If you want to specialize your `deadline/timeout` to each request then use context, otherwise, if you want 1 timeout for every outbound request then using client timeout is enough.

Comment: http.Client doesn't have timeout key for struct .Source: https://github.com/go-kit/kit/blob/v0.13.0/transport/http/client.go#L22

Comment: @Aladdin, you may try to `SetClient` with the parameter `http.Client{
    Timeout: 3 * time.Second,
}` and this `http.Client` is imported from `net/http`

Answer (score 12):

A quick and dirty way:

```
http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).ResponseHeaderTimeout = time.Second * 45
```

This is mutating global state w/o any coordination. Yet it might be possibly okay for your url fetcher. Otherwise create a private instance of `http.RoundTripper`:

```
var myTransport http.RoundTripper = &http.Transport{
        Proxy:                 http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
        ResponseHeaderTimeout: time.Second * 45,
}

var myClient = &http.Client{Transport: myTransport}

resp, err := myClient.Get(url)
...
```

Nothing above was tested.

Comment: Please anyone correct me, but it looks like the ResponseHeaderTimeout is about the read timeout, that is the timeout after the connection has been established. The most comprehensive solution seems to be the one by @dmichael, as it allows to set both the dial timeout and the read timeout.

Comment: `http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).ResponseHeaderTimeout = time.Second * 45` help me alot in write test for request timeout. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
timeout := time.Duration(5 * time.Second)
transport := &http.Transport{Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl), ResponseHeaderTimeout:timeout}
```

This may help, but notice that `ResponseHeaderTimeout` starts only after the connection is established.