# Default HTTP dial timeout value in golang

Tags: http, go

I am running a golang http client to stress test a server. Sometimes I got error "dial tcp 161.170.xx.xxx:80: operation timed out" error.

I think this is a HTTP client timeout. I am thinking about increase the timeout value based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/16895878/198497, but I would like to find out what's the default timeout value in golang first. If it is depends on os instead of language, how can I check this value in Mac OS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dialer :

```
type Dialer struct {
        // Timeout is the maximum amount of time a dial will wait for
        // a connect to complete. If Deadline is also set, it may fail
        // earlier.
        //
        // The default is no timeout.
        //
        // With or without a timeout, the operating system may impose
        // its own earlier timeout. For instance, TCP timeouts are
        // often around 3 minutes.
```

So the default timeout, without taking into account OS imposed limits is none.

The timeout can be set with [`SetDeadline`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPConn.SetDeadline).

The default OSX timeout can (I think) be checked with `sysctl net.inet.tcp`.