# How can I simulate a TCP dial timeout?

Tags: go, tcp

We encountered some TCP dial timeout issues when the node's (we use Kubernetes) CPU load is high: user received 504 status code after request exceeds 30 seconds, but the server never received those requests.

We use Traefik as our Ingress: [forwardingtimeoutsdialtimeout - Traefik](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/overview/#forwardingtimeoutsdialtimeout), I want to figure out if this caused the problem. How can I simulate a TCP dial timeout error for test?

Timeout requests (time/request_time/upstream_status):

[image]

CPU usage:

[image]

Comment: How to simulate a dial timeout in what code? Most packages use a `Dial` or `DialContext` function of some sort, which you can do whatever you want with.

Answer (score -3):

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "time"
)

    func main() {
        app := gin.Default()
        app.GET("/", TO)
        app.Run(":4040")
    }
    func TO(c *gin.Context) {
        time.Sleep(time.Minute * 5)
        return
    }
```

defines a handler which delays response, to this if you make a request with `Dial.Timeout` less than 5 minutes. It will time out.

[How to set timeout for http.Get() requests in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895294/how-to-set-timeout-for-http-get-requests-in-golang)

shows how to set timeout value in go's native `http.Client`

Comment: This is an HTTP timeout, not a TCP dial timeout.